# how to measure channel busy time in veins?

Tags: omnet++

is there any function that returns channel busy time? I use veins-2.2, mac and decider 802.11p. if there is not such function, how measuring the channel busy time is possible?

Answer (score 4):

Channel busy time in Veins 2.2 is measured at two points: [in the Phy layer](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-2.2/src/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc#L520) and [in the Mac layer](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-2.2/src/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L759). Both record a corresponding scalar value at the end of the simulation. Note that there is a difference in meaning between the two:

- Mac busy time is (in almost all cases) what you want to record: it records how many seconds the Mac treated the channel as busy. Divide the scalar `totalBusyTime` by the total simulation time and you know the fraction of time that the Mac could not send.
- Phy busy time is calculated very different: its value `busyTime` increases for each frame received above the sensitivity threshold. To give an example, if 1 frame is being received at any given time during the simulation, the value of this scalar would be 100%. If 4 frames are interfering for all of your simulation, the value of this scalar would be 400% (which is different to the Mac busy time you probably want).